# Possibility to prove that a function in big-theta is in big-O and little-o

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I understand that many similar questions of this sort have been asked, but in this case, the solution does not appear to be provable - or is it?

Question: If $f(n) = \Theta (g(n))$ and $g(n) = o(h(n))$ then $f(n) = O(h(n))$

Current solution:

$f(n) = \Theta (g(n))$ implies that $c_1 . g(n) \le f(n) \le c_2 . g(n)$ for $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\forall n \ge k_1$ Call this equation $1$.

$g(n) = o(h(n))$ implies that $g(n) < c_3 . h(n) $ for $c_3 \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\forall n \ge k_1$ Call this equation $2$.

Multiply $2$ by $c_2$.

$c_2 . g(n) < c_2 . c_3 . h(n)$ Call this equation $3$.

From $1$ and $3$ it can be inferred that:

$f(n) \le c_2 . g(n) < c_2 . c_3 . h(n)$

Which means that $f(n) \not\le c_4 . h(n)$ (where $c_4 = c_2 . c_3$) and therefore $f(n) \not = O(h(n))$. Is this way of approaching the problem correct, or is it - as my intuition tells me - I've missed something entirely obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks like that you missed something obvious.

A stronger claim: If $f(n) = \Theta (g(n))$ and $g(n) = o(h(n))$ then $f(n) = o(h(n))$.

---

Sketch of a proof: $f$ is bounded both above and below (up to a constant factor) by $g$ asymptotically, which is informally understood as $f$ and $g$ are the same asymptotically. $g$ is dominated by $h$ asymptotically. Hence $f$ is dominated by $h$ asymptotically.

(Sure, the above sketch is no more than rephrasing the claim in English. Well, that is how you (or at least I) would like to understand and reason about the situation)

---

Here is a detailed proof.

$f(n) = \Theta (g(n))$ implies that $c_1g(n) \le f(n) \le c_2 g(n)$ for some $c_1\gt0,\,c_2\gt0,\,k_1$ and any $n \gt k_1$.

$g(n) = o(h(n))$ implies that $|g(n)| < c_3 h(n) $ for some $c_3\gt0,\,k_2$ and any $n \gt k_2$.

Let $k_3=\max(k_1,k_2),\, c_4=\max(c_1,c_2)c_3\gt0$. Then for any $n\gt k_3$,
$$\begin{align}
|f(n)|&\le \max(|c_1g(n)|, |c_2g(n)|)\\
      &\lt\max(c_1c_3h(n),c_2c_3h(n))\\
      &=\max(c_1,c_2)c_3h(n)\\
      &=c_4h(n)
\end{align}$$
Note the first inequality above is guaranteed by the fact that $f(n)$ is bounded between $c_1g(n)$ and $c_2g(n)$ since $n>k_1$.

---

Finally, note that $f(n)=o(h(n))$ implies $f(n)=O(h(n))$.

---

P.S. There is some typo in your question. For example, "$c_1, c_2\in\mathbb{N}$" should be "some $c_1,\,c_2\in\Bbb{R}^+$" or "some $c_1>0,\,c_2>0$". If you let $f(n)=n, g(n)=2n$, then there is no natural number $c_1$ such that $c_1g(n)\le f(n)$ for even one positive $n$.

Comment: TL;DR Read the definitions first...

Answer (score 0):

From $f(n) \le c_2 \cdot g(n) < c_2 \cdot c_3 . h(n)$ you can infer that $f(n) < c_4 \cdot h(n)$ with $c_4 = c_2 \cdot c_3$. Therefore $f(n) = o(h(n))$, and therefore also $f(n) = O(h(n))$, since this is a weaker statement (if $f(n) < c_4 \cdot h(n)$ is true, then certainly also $f(n) \le c_4 \cdot h(n)$ is).

---

Also notice, that you should be a little more precise with your formulations. $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$ means, that there exist some $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ with ... The inequality doesn't hold for every choice of $c_1$ and $c_2$.